# How do I export a high-res panorama with ICE?

Tags: panorama, microsoft-ice

Can I export high resolution panoramas with [Microsoft ICE](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/product/computational-photography-applications/image-composite-editor/) (Image Composite Editor)?

When I add my photos, it only allows me to export a final image 5120px wide, but if I create it with PTGui I can export to 19252px!

Is this a limitation with ICE?

**EDIT**
I think the problem is with RAW (DNG) images, if I use the JPG version it allows me to render more than 20K, with RAW the max size is 5K not sure why

Comment: You need to give us more information.  What settings are you using for export? What kind of files did you import? Post some screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such limit in ICE. You should be able to the output scale to 100% just before you export. It will give you the maximum resolution possible for your panorama. I often use ICE to make panoramas initially since it is so easy and go to something more sophisticated if it fails. There might be a limit IIRC but it is beyond 19K.

Comment: read my edit, I think is a problem with RAW data, have you tested it with CR2 images?

Comment: @Enrique No, I don't have CR2s. Could it be interpolating from the CR2 thumbnails if it cannot convert properly? Might be work updating and checking WIC Codecs which ICE uses to support RAW format. If that fail, try converting to DNG and see what you get in terms of input and output resolution.

Comment: actually the raw images were DNG, they are taken with DJI Mavic Pro

Comment: OK. Then I'm confused about why you asked about CR2 files but still check your WIC codecs.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, when trying to assemble a spherical panorama from images shot with a DJI Mini 2. I was able to solve this, by exporting the DNG images in Lightroom to TIFF, then ICE was able to create a full size panorama.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into this it seems like there is, in fact, a limit/restriction, however, that limit/restriction is 537 Megapixels, this is related to TIFF images however possible that you're using the same format?

[More information](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/428f71af-81b0-401c-856a-818517af67b2/ice-completed-stitching-of-large-tiff-80-image-composite-always-works-but-first-time-wont-export-as?forum=ice)

Comment: read my edit, I think is a problem with RAW data, have you tested it with CR2 images?